# Pass parameter with $ref in Swagger 2.0

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

```
responses:
    '201':
      description: Success
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Project_Name
```

Is there any way I can use a variable Project_Name with ref in the schema so that I can reuse this particular code snippet

Comment: Do you mean reusing the entire response definition? I.e. everything under "'201'"?

Comment: It would be nice if I can reuse the entire response definition and sending the Project_Name variable to send the project names

Comment: OpenAPI supports [reusing response definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35987551/113116). Does this answer your question?